# BOLD and ITALIC to the same text in RTF

Tags: vb.net

Can we able to format BOLD and ITALIC to the same text?

Regards,
Poornima

Comment: ***Yes, not a problem***

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
The System.Drawing.FontStyle enumeration is a flags enumeration.
To combine styles, simply use the OR operator.

Assuming you're applying the font to the selected portion of the text, it could look like:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = _
New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
```

Comment: This is an old question but it helped me.  I was using + and the AND operator.  Neither presented a syntax error.  I know it's a bitwise OR, but when you read it as English it's counterintuitive.  Thanks M.A.

Comment: Always glad when an answer is helpful